# Garmin IQ Connect read gyroscope Data from Garmin Fenix 5

Tags: sdk, connect, gyroscope, garmin

is there a way to access the gyroscope data in the Garmin Fenix 5? I wanted to develop an App which takes advantage of the Gyro built in (or ANT+ Gyro if available).

I know the Accelerometer is readable with Toybox::Sensor::Info but in the current SDK version doest seem to have any method for Gyro.

Can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, the current Connect IQ SDK does not provide (direct) access to the gyroscope. As a matter of fact, the gyroscope is **not even mentioned in the official user manual**.

Based on the research of some (avid) users, it seems that the gyroscope is internally used in order to improve tracking:

https://forums.garmin.com/forum/on-the-trail/wrist-worn/fenix-5x/155802-what-s-the-main-advantage-of-gyroscope-in-fenix-5x-please-explain

For the Fenix 3/5 there exists a `Service Test Boot Mode` where you can see gyroscope data but, as indicated above, this is not accessible from the SDK (yet).

https://www.facebook.com/GarminFenix5/photos/a.584053075128378/640524422814576/?type=3&theater

-cfs

Comment: you are right, I remember searching the SDK official docs and finding nothing related to the gyro.thank you for your comment and link!